# jQuery load() doesnt load images linked inside html file that is loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, load

Basicly I'm loading an external html file to an element using jQuery `.load()` method,but when the file loads it doesn't show images. I have tried changing the path to the images but nothing happened.
My file structure:

```
-folder_img
--image
-folder_loads
--file_to_be_loaded
-index.html
```

I have tried `../folder_img/image` and `folder_image/image` inside src attribute of my image tag inside file_to_be_loaded,but it just whant work.If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated :)

the way I'm loading it:

```
switch(dataValue) {
  case("about"):
    popover.css("background", "#37474f");
    popoverContent.load("loads/about.html");
    console.log(popoverContent);
  break;
  case("work"):
    popover.load("loads/work.html");
  break;
  case("testimonials"):
    popover.load("loads/testimonials.html");
  break;
  case("contact"):
    popover.load("loads/contact.html");
  break;
}
```

Also to mention,whan I open the file that I am loading directly in chrome images are showed...

Comment: Make sure your image URLs are relative to the page where your script loads the pages and not to the location of the pages themselves

Comment: Thanks,it seems it was a typo previously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:
`/folder_image/image`.

Comment: do you have problem just with images? check your browser console and put here the `not found` errors.

Comment: what it must be?

Comment: I don't know,but it just loaded...guessing something wierd :S ...I'm concidering it was a typo,but I changed the url 5 times back and forth and it  didn't load,and than suddenly it works...